# Binding using MVVM on Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, mvvm, windows-8.1

I am developing an app on Windows 8.1 and using MVVM Light Framework.

So this is the partial XAML on one of my views.

Basically, I have a ViewModel_Queue which I contains a command that I need to call when a button is pressed inside the FlyoutMenu. My problem is, how will I be able to call this ViewModel_Queue where inside a binding ItemControl which is inside in another ItemControl which is then binded as well?

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Person.Child}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Border Background="#FF808080" Width="200">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="15" Foreground="White" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>

                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Counters}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Width="120" Background="#0F000000">
                                <!-- get header color -->
                                <Border Height="20">
                                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                                            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.Queue.Command_DoSomething, ElementName=mainGrid}" />
                                        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                </Border>

                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Total}" FontSize="15" Foreground="Black" Margin="10" TextAlignment="Center" x:Name="outcomeCounterCell" Tapped="outcomeCounterCell_Tapped">
                                    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                                        <Flyout Placement="Bottom" x:Name="MenuFlyout" FlyoutPresenterStyle="{StaticResource FlyoutPresenterRoundStyle}">
                                            <Grid Width="200">
                                                <StackPanel>
                                                    <Border Background="#7FFF0000" CornerRadius="8,8,0,0">
                                                        <TextBlock Text="Update" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" Margin="0,10" Foreground="White" />
                                                    </Border>

                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Total}" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="30" Margin="0,20,0,0" Foreground="Black" />

                                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,20">
                                                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#7F000000" CornerRadius="5,0,0,5" Width="50">
                                                            <TextBlock Text=" - " TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,5" />

                                                            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                                                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                                                                    <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Command_Decrement}" CommandParameter="{Binding }" />
                                                                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                                                            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                                        </Border>
                                                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#7F000000" CornerRadius="0,5,5,0" Width="50">
                                                            <TextBlock Text=" + " TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,5" />

                                                            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                                                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                                                                    <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Command_Increment}" CommandParameter="{Binding }" />
                                                                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                                                            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                                        </Border>
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Flyout>
                                    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: So you have a model lets say A that is inside another model B and you wanna call the command that is in A?

Comment: Have you tried doing B.A.command?